# how does serializable work in java?

Tags: java, serialization

If I have an instance of a class that I store in a session I need to make it serializable. This class has a static variable, will this be serialized in every instance stored?

The static variable is a reference to a cache containing a lot of data in the background. Will all of this data be serialized? If so, it seems preferable to make this variable transient and re-fetch the cache instance each time the instance is restored. Maybe not store the cache instance at all in the class.

Will the constructor execute when a class is restored from a serialized state? if not is there any other method I can use to re-instate a transient variable?

Comment: The no-arg constructor of the most derived non-serialisable super class is executed, but not the constructors of the serialised classes. `readObject` (or `readObjectNoData` can replace the default deserialisation (see the API docs).

Comment: @Tom, replace? So if I implement one of those methods I need to handle all of the serialization by myself?

Comment: Trumstedt Generally you would supply (not override) `readObject`. The first thing that method should do is call `defaultReadObject` or `readFields`.

Comment: @Tom, OK, i get it. Now if I have a static field which is not serialized, I need to make sure in the readObject method that the static field is instanciated once more if it has no value (no other class has assiged it yet)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> This class has a static variable, will
>   this be serialized in every instance
>   stored?

No. According to the [Java Object Serialization Specificaiton](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#6250): "Default serializable fields of a class are defined to be the non-transient and non-static fields."

> Will the constructor execute when a class is restored from a serialized state?

No. Deserialization bypasses constructors (unless you have a non-serializable superclass).

> if not is there any other method I can use to re-instate a transient variable?

You can use the `readObject()` method for that, as described in the [`Serializable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) API doc.

Comment: You always have a non-serialisable superclass.

Answer (score 3):

static and transient fields are not serialized.  No, the constructor is not called.  For more details, please check this out: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/serialization/

Comment: Static can be serialized, you may want to look at http://www.ecst.csuchico.edu/~amk/foo/advjava/notes/serial.htm

Comment: Thanks for your response, but please check the link. I couldn't get it to work.  Though my interpretation of the question is will a static variable be serialized by default with each instance, and afaik, the default behavior for serialization is that static data is not serialized since it is not considered to be part of the state of the object.

Comment: Thanks, great link which does explain how to serialize class-specific information and it makes sense that it should not be serialized with the instance information.  I have Core Java by Horstmann and Cornell -- a great pair of books.  Again, thanks!