# Does the default constructor get called during object deserialization when using ObjectInputStream?

Tags: java, serialization

New to Java and I was using [browxy](http://www.browxy.com/SavedCode/4318) to try and answer this question and it doesnt allow creation of files.

So I was wondering if in the following code, when readObject gets called, does it call the default constructor (if one exists) or not? (also, is there a MemoryStream (C#) equivalent in Java?)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");

        try
        {
            TestClass tc = new TestClass();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("t.tmp");
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                oos.writeObject(tc);
                oos.close();

                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("t.tmp");
                    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

                    TestClass tcClone = (TestClass)ois.readObject();

                    ois.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

  }
}

class TestClass implements Serializable
{
    public TestClass()
    {
        System.out.println("TestClass CTOR");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ways to find it: 1) put a `println/log` in your constructor 2) try to deserialize a class without default constructor.

Comment: AFAIK It uses sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateInstance() on OpenJDK/HotSPot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641669/how-does-serializable-work-in-java (and a bunch of others ... out of close and down votes)

Comment: closing my own question (duplicate). Answer is No - it doesnt call default ctor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was wondering if in the following code, when readObject gets called,
>   does it call the default constructor (if one exists) or not?

No, It doesn't ..

> is there a MemoryStream (C#) equivalent in Java?

`ByteArrayInputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream`

Answer (score 4):

For classes that implement `java.io.Externalizable`, the public no-arg constructor is called.

For other serialisable classes, the accessible no-arg constructor of the most derived non-serialisable base class is called. The serialisable classes' `readObject` methods are called as if the are constructors (or at least, constructor bodies immediately after returning from calling the super constructor).

It's a common misunderstanding that serialisable classes need a public no-arg constructor. They do not.

`java.lang.String` and enums are handled specially.